# Displaying video on UWP and WASM

Tags: uwp, webassembly, uno-platform

I have an Uno app that I'd like to display media on both the UWP and WASM platforms.  Mostly images (jpg) but also the occasional .mov.  I am using an itemselector with the following datatemplate for the .mov file:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MovTemplate" x:DataType="vm:PictureViewModel">
    <Grid Margin="4">
        <!--<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Filename}" NavigateUri="{Binding MediaUri}" />-->
       <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mplayerElement" Source="{Binding MediaUri}" Width="{Binding Parent.ImageWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="400" 
             AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The MediaPlayerElement appears on UWP, however, it does not play any media. On WASM, it does not appear.  I have substituted the HyperlinkButton to verify that the link is correct (commented out). On android, it appears and functions properly. Does the MediaPlayerElement not support .mov is UWP and WASM environments?
How can I display .mov or other video types (mp4, wmv) on UWP and WASM?

Comment: derive from document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/supported-media-formats-in-media-foundation#file-containers) mov file extension is MPEG-4 format, and it could play by MediaPlayerElement. please check if you have passed correct MediaUri

Comment: Have you found a fix? I am following Uno Platform tutorial, I am having all kinds of errors even following every step in the tutorial. I played with UWP a while ago, every simple task seemed like a brain surgery in UWP. Is Uno Platform mature enough?

Comment: The specific error message is "The file's parent is not accessible, so we cannot move the file to rename it."  How can I correct this?